# drop down with onchange events

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a dropdown with `onchange` events. When ever user change the drop down box then ajax called and result displayed. All this working fine.

I have following list in template.

```
Apple
Pineapple
```

When ever user changed the drop down value. Then result merged

```
Orange
Graps

Apple
Pineapple
```

But output should be like this.

```
Orange
Graps
```

I have no idea what to do. Please help me. Here is my [base](http://dpaste.org/gobq7/). Here is my [movie_list](http://dpaste.org/bk5pi/) template. Here is my [movie_sort](http://dpaste.org/JuR8Z/) template. And here is my [view](http://dpaste.org/PSXik/) . Thanks :-)

UPDATE: Here is ajax code.

```
   function sortMovie(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/moviesort/?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

DROP DOWN

```
           <select name="category" onchange="sortMovie(this.value)">
                <option value="">Choose</option>
                {% for category in categories %}
                <option value="{{ category.id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}                    
                </select>
```

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442104/what-is-the-best-jquery-multiselect-picker-for-hierarchical-data

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery to call ajax, I would recommend you use the .empty() straight after the .change() function.

I have no idea what yours looks like, although it should be something like this.

```
$('#id_category').change(function() {
    /* Set your string to nothing */
    var str = "";
    /* once your dropdown is changed, it performs a look and gets the new data */
    $("#id_category option:selected").each(function () {
        /* Before inserting the new data, empty out all the old items */
        $('#id_sub_category').empty();
        str += $(this).val();
        $.get('{% url gear_category %}', { category: str }, function(data){
            $(data).appendTo("#id_sub_category");
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using simple ajax function not jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ApPel on this.

However, since you aren't using jQuery...

You'll either have to loop through each option in the select and remove as you go, or I suppose if pure javascript supports you might be able to mimic the jQuery code, but with the javascript syntax.

Either way, you'll have to remove the old values before appending the new ones. That's the problem.